# CSS Specificity in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a question about CSS specificity.

This style is in a `<style>` tag on a page.

```
.m-order-returnable-item .itemdescdetails li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

This style is in a CSS file and linked from the page

```
div.account ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

For the padding property, I want the first style to win.

The first style has a stronger CSS specificity than the second style, but in Chrome 36, the second style wins instead.  In Firefox 31, the first style wins.

EDIT: Changed `padding-bottom: 5px 0;` to `padding-bottom: 5px;`  Chrome works properly now.  But, even in the mistaken version, Firefox was able to handle the error. (According to Firebug, Firefox interpreted `padding-bottom: 5px 0;` as `padding: 0 0 5px`. I guess Chrome is less tolerant, which is probably a good thing, or I would not have caught the mistake!

Comment: It might have to do with using padding-bottom in one situation and padding: 0 in the other.

Comment: That and padding-bottom should only have 1 value.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex: The cascading behavior of shorthand vs longhand is well-defined - a shorthand acts as though all its longhands were being set, with missing values represented as their defaults. That being said, if the given behavior is reproducible, then at least one of the browsers is handling this incorrectly.

Comment: @BoltClock but is it defined as to what happens when padding-bottom is using two values?

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex: Yes: it's invalid and should be ignored ;)

Comment: Michael pointed out the mistake with two values in the padding-bottom property.  I changed that and Chrome as now honoring that.  Sorry for the run-around over nothing, but thanks for the extra set of eyes everybody.

Comment: "Firefox was able to handle the error" That'd be the first time I've seen Firefox do something like that.

Comment: Firefox somehow interpreted padding-bottom: 5px 0; correctly!  In Firebug, it said the interpretation was padding: 0 0 5px.